# Angular - [(ngModel)] vs [ngModel] vs (ngModel)

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-ngmodel

I currently understand that `[(ngModel)]="expression"` is two-way binding from component to view and vice versa. I also understand that `[ngModel]="expression"` is one-way binding (I believe from component to view?). Then there's the possibility of `(ngModel)="expression"`. I am mostly confused as to the differences between `[ngModel]` vs `(ngModel)`. Could someone please explain?

**EDIT:** After playing around with, and reviewing the document snippet given by @Rohan Fating I realized that something like `(ngModel)` should take a statement, rather than an expression. That being said, would there ever be an appropriate time to use something like `(ngModel)` or would that even work in any circumstance?

Comment: Its the one way binding going the other way

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This syntax:

```
[(ngModel)]="expression"
```

is unwrapped by the compiler into

```
[ngModel]="expression" (ngModelChange)="expression=$event"
```

which means:

1. there's a ngModel directive applied to an element (input)
2. this ngModel directive through ngModel binding takes the `expression` parameter
3. there's an output (event) `ngModelChange`

Now you can see that `[ngModel]` part is always there which as you noted will sync values down.

What happens when you specify `(ngModel)="c()"` is interesting. Normally, the `(...)` syntax is for events. So indeed Angular recognizes this as event and create appropriate listener in the [component view factory](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-why-you-will-not-find-components-inside-angular-bdaf204d955c#4e19):

```
function (_v, en, $event) {
    var ad = true;
    var _co = _v.component;
    ...
    if (('ngModel' === en)) {
        var pd_4 = (_co.c() !== false);
        ad = (pd_4 && ad);
    }
    return ad;
}
```

However, all `(...)` elements **are also parsed as attributes**, and so it will match the `ngModel` directive selector:

```
selector: '[ngModel]:not([formControlName]):not([formControl])'
```

so Angular will also initialize the `ngModel` directive class as a directive. However, since it doesn't have any input bindings defined through `[...]` syntax this directive will be skipped during change detection. And since also the event `ngModel` is not defined for the `ngModel` directive the usage `(ngModel)` will have no side effects and is meaningless.

Answer (score 6):

[image]`[(` in Angular is signalling a two-way data binding. Theoretically you could only bind to an event (`(ngModel)`) or to a value (`[ngModel]`). This gives you the ability to handle changes going down in a different way than changes coming up. With Angular 2 you have that flexibility.

You need to ngModelChange event and update value like I did below

Plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/RZMgM69doSHGBG1l16Qf?p=preview

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
    <input [ngModel]='value' (ngModelChange)='setModel($event)'/>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  value: string = '';
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }

  setModel(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

}
```

Comment: So `(ngModel)` would be considered an event binding? Meaning the user inputted data, and I want to read what they input? Whereas if I use `[ngModel]` I am only wanting to change the value a user sees, but they cannot effect that value?

Comment: Added screen shot and you can refer this link from angular.io :::   https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview

Comment: After testing out `(ngModel)="expression"` I realized it's not adding the inputted value to the model in my component. Is this because `ngModel` isn't considered an event?

Comment: Also my question doesn't necessarily have to do with the binding, as much as it does the specifics of `[ngModel]` vs `(mgModel)`. Does `(ngModel)` even work?

Comment: Updaed answer with code,, ngModelChange event we need to bind for event binding but [ngModel] should always be there. model change would be require to perform some action on change of input basically.

Answer (score 6):

[(ngModel)] is two way binding 
(NgModel) is one Way binding view to component
[ngModel] is one way binding component to view

Comment: I edited my question above. I tried using `(ngModel)="exampleObj.foo"` but realized that it does not bind to the object on my component like I would expect.